# Where should I register JSON marshallers in a grails plugin?

Tags: grails

I am creating a grails plugin and want to know where JSON marshallers should be registered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [article](http://compiledammit.com/2012/08/16/custom-json-marshalling-in-grails-done-right/) will help you.

Just register the bean in your plugin's **"YourpluginPlugin.groovy"** (in **doWithSpring** clojure) and call `register()` method from your plugin as well.